# How to implement Database transaction operations like commit,rollback?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, transaction

I want use them like this:

```
Start Transaction; //What to write here? 

    $userModel->setAdmin_id('1')
                    ->setEmail('abc@xyz.com')
                    ->save();

    $profileModel->setProfile_id('1')
                 ->setAccount_name('xyz')
                 ->save();

Commit Transaction; //What to write here?
```

Comment: That isn't a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you are inside a resource model, because database transaction is nothing for a normal model.

if you are, then just do:

```
\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::beginTransaction
$this->beginTransaction();

\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::commit
$this->commit();

\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::rollBack
$this->rollback();
```